# android : Validate User ID

Tags: android, regex, string, validation, format

I want to check that user entered a valid user id name in the registration activity

User ID should take alphanumeric characters besides . - _ 
should start with letter and can not have . - _ in the beginning or the end or duplicated 
user id should start with letter

I used this but does not seem to be working,

```
UserID.matches("^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9 ].*$")
```

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: did you want to allow `. - _ `?

Comment: yes, similar to the email id, it can be Alex.Thomas or Tom-Jerry or George_Gallowy

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `\\w` in the regex to match alphanumeric characters plus an `_` symbol.

```
[A-Za-z][\\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iX8hF3/10)

```
System.out.println("Alex.Thomas".matches("[A-Za-z][\\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]"));
System.out.println("George_Gallowy".matches("[A-Za-z][\\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]"));
System.out.println("George_Gallowy.".matches("[A-Za-z][\\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]"));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: I just changed it to this ^[A-Za-z][\w.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$    thx